# spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE-yarn, log file locatoin

Tags: logging, hadoop-yarn, spring-xd

If anyone knows where the log file locations, please help me.
I also changed the files xd-admin-logger.properties and xd-container-logger.properties to point to a specific location like below, but I can't see any logs in it.

```
log=/var/log/logs
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
```

If you know a default log file location without file changes, it would be helpful as well.
Thank you in advance.